# Call bean's method after update action in commandButton

Tags: ajax, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I tried something like this:

```
<p:commandButton type="push" value="Ack" disabled="false"
    oncomplete="bean.method2()" update=":form:alarmTable"
    action="#{bean.method1()}"
```

But method2 does not invoke, otherwise:

```
<p:commandButton type="push" value="Ack" disabled="false"
    oncomplete="alert('onComplete')" update=":form:alarmTable"
    action="#{bean.method1()}"
```

works as expected.

I want to implement next chain of action: method1 - update - method2.
How do to that?

Comment: `oncomplete` is a javascript event. Why do you need another request after update? What's your use case? It feels strange. I'd rather not rely on such request/response/request chain.

Comment: I tend to agree with @PeterGwiazda. But if it's just an UI thing, maybe what you want is to automatically "click" another hidden commandButton?

Comment: Can't your method1 call method2? or try add process="@this,IdMehtod2commandButton", but the all the two options will execute method2 before, update but after method1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everyone else agrees, you probably shouldn't be trying to call a method in your view. What you should do is call your method2 from method1 in your backer.

example:

```
public void method1() {
  // do stuff
  method2();
}

public void method2() {
  // do stuff
}
```